# Java Scanner's nextLine() method gives no line found

Tags: java

I have wasted hours with this simple problem but I could not figure out why nextLine() cannot find the next line. Please help me, thank you!

I tried this code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-nextline-method-in-java-with-examples/ as an experiment and naturally it worked but my own will not.

Variable "test" is copied from the file.

Code portion:

ObservableList adatok;

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    int lines = 0;
    try {
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\EDU_BYQN_0965\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JSZ_SB\\src\\jsz_sb\\fokonyvi_kivonat.txt");
    String test = "113,Vagyoni értékű jogok,3600,0,\n" +
            "1173,Vagyoni értékű jogok értékhelyesbítése,360,0,\n" +
            "1193,Vagyoni értékű jogok értékcsökkenése,0,2400,\n" +
            "5,t,5,5,";

    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    while (s.hasNext() && s.nextLine() != null) lines++;
    String[][] array = new String[lines][4];
    String[] temporary = new String[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        temporary = s.nextLine().split(",");
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            array[i][j]=temporary[j];
            adatok = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new TrialBalance(array[i][0], array[i][1], Integer.parseInt(array[i][2]), Integer.parseInt(array[i][3])));               
        }            
    }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXML_scene2Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Array "temporary" should contain the first line of the file, leastwise at the first loop and runtime error should not appear.

Comment: You've already reached the end of file in `while (s.hasNext() && s.nextLine() != null) lines++;`. You should reopen file. Better, use `List` instead of arrays

Comment: Thank you for your help, I managed to solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You exhaust the `Scanner` in this line:

```
while (s.hasNext() && s.nextLine() != null) lines++;
```

It stops because there are no more lines. (Note that the check `hasNext()` pairs with a call to `next()`, and `hasNextLine()` pairs with `nextLine()`).

So, if you try to read any more lines from the `Scanner`, there is nothing more to read.

You either need to create a new instance of the `Scanner`; or use a data structure that you don't need to know the size of a-priori, like a `List` (or resize your array as required; but there is little point in doing this "by hand" when `ArrayList` does that for you transparently).

Comment: Thank you a lot, I instantiated a new Scanner and I could proceed.

Comment: @Balint9004, I still strongly recommend you to use `List` instead of array. It will be both clearer, less error-prone and faster (reading from file is pretty slow; no need to do it twice).

Comment: @dyukha I have taken your advice and changed my code to this: ArrayList<String[]> array = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        while (s.hasNextLine() && s.nextLine() != null)
        {      
             array.add(s.nextLine().split(","));
                adatok = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new TrialBalance(array.get(0), array.get(1), Integer.parseInt(array.get(2)),Integer.parseInt(array.get(3))));                                    
        }  //But I get String[] cannot be converted to String at array.get() methods.

Comment: (By the way this FXCollections.observableArrayList() is used to fill javafx tableview with data and this table automatically refreshes when I make a new TrialBalance object as seen above: adatok = …) Could you help me?

Comment: @Balint9004, instead of `array.get(0)` you want `array.get(i)[0]`. You can just use `temporary` variable. `temporary = s.nextLine().split(",");`, `array.ad(temporary)`, `new TrialBalance(temporary[0], ...`

Comment: Thanks, by your help and by other slight modifications my program runs as expected. Hooray! :D